# Change react state using button from a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a little bit new to react (javascript in general) so I'll apologize in advance if I misname a few terms! Thanks for bearing with me.

I have a login function and a signup function both returning their respective content. Now, both components (functions? Still confused on what to name them exactly) contain a button that will link them together

Signup **button clicked** -> Login
Login **button clicked** -> Signup
You get the idea.

This is my current method!

*controllerComponent.jsx*

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "./loginComponent";
import Signup from "./signupComponent";

let login;

export const handleButton = () => {
    login = !login;
}

export default function Contact(){
    return (
        <div>
            {login === true ? <Login /> : <Signup />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then I call the following functions from the signup/login functions.
*signupComponent.jsx* and *loginComponent.jsx*

```
//imports
import {handleButton} from "./controllerComponent";

export default function Signup() {
    //stuff
    const handleLogin = () => {
         handleButton();
    }
    return (
        //return including button
        //all other information
        <Button
            onClick={handleLogin}
            className={classes.button}
        >
            Back
        </Button>
    );
}
```

I think this is because the state of *controllerComponent* is not being changed. What would be a good way to make this happen? Or if anyone has any other suggestions for handling the change between Login/Signup I'll be happy to hear it!

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because the only wait for React to trigger a rerender of the component is when `state` of you component change. In your component you haven't define any state. So event If you call the `handleButton` function which is supposed to change the value of your variable `login` It won't trigger the rerender of the component

So to fix that

You define the `Contact` component like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Contact(){
    const [ login, setLogin ] = useState(false);

    const handleLogin = () => {
        setLogin(!login);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {login === true ? 
                 <Login login={handleLogin}/> : 
                 <Signup login={handleLogin}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And the `Signup` Component like this

```
export default function Signup(props) {
    
    return (
        <Button
            onClick={props.login}
            className={classes.button}
        >
            Back
        </Button>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer seemed to work perfect, but small edit: `const {login, setLogin} = useState(false)` has to be `const [login, setLogin] = useState(false)`. Atleast that was causing an error for me.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is to move handleButton inside the Contact component and then pass it to both Login and SignUp as a prop like this:

```
<Login handlebutton={this.handleButton} />
```

And inside each component change onClick to

```
onClick = {this.props.handleButton}
```

Comment: Works well! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `let login;` to store the login state variable, you need to use a [react state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

So inside your functional component, add:

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

const handleLogin = () => setIsLoggedIn(!isLoggedIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<Login />` and `<Signup />` will need to receive `onSubmit` props, that way the parent component can inject some function.

Signup.js

```js
const Signup = (props) => {
  const onSubmit = () => {
    const values = {...};
    props.onSubmit(values);
  }
  return (
    <Form>
      <Button onClick={onSubmit} />
    </Form>
  );
```

Login.js

```js
const Login = (props) => {
  const onSubmit = () => {
    const values = {...};
    props.onSubmit(values);
  }
  return (
    <Form>
      <Button onClick={onSubmit} />
    </Form>
  );
```

Page.js

```
const onLogin = () => ...request api and handle other functions...
const onSignup = () => ...request api and handle other functions...

return (
  <div>
    {login === true ? <Login onSubmit={onLogin} /> : <Signup onSubmit={onSignup } />}
  </div>
);
```